# How can I integrate Firefox with KDE's theme?

Tags: 11.04, firefox, kubuntu

When using Firefox in Kubuntu the difference between KDE's theme and Firefox's theme is huge. Is there any way to make the theme in Firefox look like the one in Ubuntu all smooth, fonts with correct size, etc.. Right now, Firefox in KDE makes everything like it was made 10 years ago with mspaint. The fonts are very small and it does not look good.

Comment: why don't you give chrome a go?

Comment: Already have it but i need to develop using firefox and chrome. And Firefox is more compatible for my needs indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install a GTK+ theme that's compatible with your KDE theme

i'm using oxygen for KDE and installed the oxygen-gtk theme to have all my GTK+ apps look like my Qt apps

Answer (score -1):

First you need to conpfigure GTK fonts on KDE control center (now don't ask me how because I haven't used KDE in a while)

Second, for eeh theme, download the kde4 theme from mozilla addons or from kde look

https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/addon/oxygen-kde/

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=117962

Comment: those add-ons don't work in the latest FF

Comment: the latest, wich you can dwnload from the mozilla site DOES

Comment: sorry, tried to install that about a month a ago and no dice

Comment: It was there more than a month ago >.<